# How can I insert the value of an input into inputs below it

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Basically if I input 100 in row3, row4 and row5 the rows below it will also get 100 inserted into them. Is this possible to do?

HMTL

```
<input id="row1">
<input id="row2">
<input id="row3">
<input id="row4">
<input id="row5">
```

Comment: The `.nextAll()` function should be useful for this.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the help man, I really appreciate it.

Comment: You need to translate what you want with something like an algorithm, then you can code it easily. Would "I want each input with ID=X to inherit the value from the input with ID X-1" do what you have in mind? If so, you just need to define an event on which you need these checks to happen and you're good to go.

Comment: @alou thanks for help, I will look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.nextAll()` method will select all the following siblings that match a selector. So you can do

```js
$("input[id^=row]").change(function() {
    $(this).nextAll("input[id^=row]").val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="row1">
<input id="row2">
<input id="row3">
<input id="row4">
<input id="row5">
```